# Get the Last Access date for all BigQuery tables in a BigQuery Project

Tags: google-bigquery

I know how to get the date a table was last modified, but not accessed. Is it possible to get the last time a table was read ? Is there query or an API to get this ?

Comment: You can use Audit Logs to analyze BigQuery Resources usage - check https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/audit-logs

Answer (score 2):

If you have [audit logs](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/audit-logs) in BigQuery, you can write a query like this:

```
WITH tables AS (
  SELECT FORMAT("%s.%s.%s", table.projectId, table.datasetId, table.tableId) table
    , MAX(timestamp) last_access
  FROM (
    SELECT timestamp
      , protopayload_auditlog.servicedata_v1_bigquery.jobCompletedEvent.job.jobStatistics.referencedTables  
    FROM `fh-bigquery.audit.cloudaudit_googleapis_com_data_access_201811*`
  ), UNNEST(referencedTables) table
  GROUP BY 1
)

SELECT * 
FROM tables
```

[image]

Comment: I know it was posted a time ago but I'd just like to rise an important point of it. When **wildcard** tables are queried like `FROM tbl_shard_*` using the suggested technique is not satisfactory as the returned referenced table is `tbl_shard_*` – **rather than every scanned shard instead**. A possible workaround, would be checking `_TABLE_SUFFIX` text to grab all the shards. It's not 100% reliable yet as in cases of subquery under `_TABLE_SUFFIX` "we wouldn't know the result". After all updates and new releases, may you know if is there any alternative solution for it? Tks

Comment: What permissions are required to query `fh-bigquery.audit.cloudaudit_googleapis_com_data_access_201811` or whatever table is used for this audit querying?

Comment: Google might have deleted the data I shared (I've been working with Snowflake for the last >2 years)

Answer (score 0):

I was also looking to get a last-accessed property for several tables. Here's a query that seems to be working for me so far.

```
SELECT table_id,
    DATE(TIMESTAMP_MILLIS(TABLES.creation_time)) AS creation_date,
    MAX(JOBS.end_time) as last_accessed,
    TABLES.dataset_id,
    TABLES.project_id
FROM `[project-id].[dataset-id].__TABLES__` TABLES
LEFT OUTER JOIN
     `[project-id].region-us.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.JOBS` JOBS
ON TABLES.table_id = JOBS.destination_table.table_id
GROUP BY table_id, creation_date, TABLES.dataset_id, TABLES.project_id
HAVING last_accessed <= "2023-01-01" OR last_accessed IS NULL
ORDER BY last_accessed ASC
```

The idea was to `JOIN` against the jobs log which are stored in the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.JOBS` and checking when was the latest query executed.