# Last access date for bigquery tables

Tags: google-bigquery

Is there any way to get the 'last accessed' date of tables in BigQuery? I found the same question 
[Get the Last Access date for all BigQuery tables in a BigQuery Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53310574/get-the-last-access-date-for-all-bigquery-tables-in-a-bigquery-project)

but couldn't post a comment nor reply, so I'm asking again.

Where to get this table? ->  FROM `fh-bigquery.audit.cloudaudit_googleapis_com_data_access_201811*`

My bQ project ID is 'test-247020', while my data set name is BabyName.

How do I make this work?

Thanks a lot for your help.

---

updating the query I'm using:

```
 WITH tables AS (
  SELECT FORMAT("%s.%s.%s", table.projectId, table.datasetId, table.tableId) table
    , MAX(timestamp) last_access
  FROM (
    SELECT timestamp
      , protopayload_auditlog.servicedata_v1_bigquery.jobCompletedEvent.job.jobStatistics.referencedTables  
    FROM `test-247020.BabyName.cloudaudit_googleapis_com_data_access`
  ), UNNEST(referencedTables) table
  GROUP BY 1
)

SELECT * 
FROM tables
```

Comment: read again that answer

Answer (score 2):

Google Cloud Platform offers different ways to retrieve information about BigQuery jobs and datasets/tables.

1 - The BigQuery web UI:

On the left side panel of the [BigQuery web UI](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/bigquery-web-ui), one can find the “Query history” where the execution details related to the queries tested against different datasets are displayed. The last one will appear on top if the jobs are sorted by date. In addition, the “Project history” tab expands the previous information to the whole project. This way, it is possible to see the queries carried out by particular users.

2 - Stackdriver Logging:

[Stackdriver Logging](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/) is very useful while checking logs from different Google Cloud Platform products. 
With the following [Advanced filter](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/view/advanced-queries), one can retrieve the [output logs corresponding to queries executed in BigQuery](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/auditlogs/):

```
resource.type="bigquery_project"
protoPayload.methodName="google.cloud.bigquery.v2.JobService.InsertJob"
```

By selecting the “Last hour” and “Jump to now” options, the last accessed data will appear at the bottom of the logs panel.

It is also possible to [export](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/export/configure_export_v2) a particular Stackdriver logging configuration of a given dataset into BigQuery. This will create a new table containing the log info of the queries executed against the selected dataset. Everytime such export is updated, new logs are loaded into the logs table.

3 - Cloud Shell:

Another way to get the info of the last accessed table is to make use of the `bq`  [command](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/bq-command-line-tool) in the [Cloud Shell](https://cloud.google.com/shell/). The following bash script will retrieve all the data related to the last query in JSON format.

```
#!/bin/bash

# Get the jobID of the last executed query
LAST_JOB_ID=$(bq ls -j -a | grep query | head -1 | awk '{print $1}')

echo Query $LAST_JOB_ID job info
# retrieving the job_ID info in json format
bq show --format=prettyjson -j $LAST_JOB_ID
```

The corresponding dataset name, projectID and table name can be found in the field “referencedTables”:

```
"referencedTables": [
        {
          "datasetId": "DATASET”,
          "projectId": "PROJECTID",
          "tableId": "TABLE"
        }
      ]
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to export the logs [from Logging to BigQuery](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/export/configure_export_v2) first.

Answer (score 0):

I went to the logs explorer and the following query works -

```
resource.type="bigquery_resource"
protoPayload.authorizationInfo.resource="projects/<PROJECT_NAME>/datasets/<DATASET_NAME>/tables/<TABLE_NAME>"
protoPayload.methodName="jobservice.insert"
```